# Scrapy Request method‘s meta-args is shallow copy，but the Request method‘s meta-args is deep copy in scrapy_redis.Why?

Tags: scrapy

**scrapy:**

```
import scrapy
from  scrapy.spider import Request

class TestspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'testspider'
    allowed_domains = ['mzitu.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.mzitu.com/']

    def start_requests(self):
        L =[]
        print("L-id:",id(L),"first")
        yield Request(url="http://www.mzitu.com/5675",callback=self.parse,meta={"L":L},dont_filter=True)
    def parse(self, response):
        L = response.meta.get('L')
        print("L-id:", id(L),"second")
```

**The ouput:**

> L-id: 2769118042568 first
>
> L-id: 2769118042568 second
>
> They're equal
>
> This is shallow copy

**scrapy_redis**

```
from scrapy_redis.spiders import RedisSpider
from scrapy.spider import Request

class MzituSpider(RedisSpider):   #scrapy_redis
    name = 'mzitu'
    redis_key = 'a:a'             #this is discard
    def start_requests(self):     #Because Rewrite the method of RedisSpider
        L =[]
        print("L-id:",id(L),"first")
        yield Request(url="http://www.mzitu.com/5675",callback=self.parse,meta={"L":L},dont_filter=True)
    def parse(self, response):
        L = response.meta.get('L')
        print("L-id:", id(L),"second")
```

**The output:**

> L-id: 1338852857992
>
> first L-id: 1338852858312 second
>
> They're not equal
>
> This is deep copy

**Question：**

> I want to know why?
>
> And how can i Solve it？
>
> Let the scrapy_redis change to become shallow copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that `scrapy-redis` uses its own scheduler class which serializes/deserializes all requests through redis before pushing them further to the downloader (it keeps a queue on redis). There is no "easy" way around this as it's basically the core `scrapy-redis` functionality. My advise is to not put too much runtime sensitive stuff into meta as this even generally not the best idea in scrapy.

Comment: Thank your answer,but i want to transfer some runtime sensitive argument such as list，from this level to the next level,and then i append something argument to the list  in the next level,finally,i "yield" my item to pipeline

Comment: @JKingKong, are you really sure it's runtime sensitive? Usually when you sequentially from request to request update an item in the meta it is just fine to let it be copied/serialized, what exactly is your issue with item being deep copied when passed further the chain? Also may I ask if you are using multiple instances of your spider running at a time or only a single one?

Comment: just only  using a spider instance.my item:     ###
(title = scrapy.Field() #pictures' title)       ###
(url = scrapy.Field()  # the first webpage url） ###       
(img_list_urls = scrapy.Field()  #this is a list,when i  paging,the program will get  a img_url put in the list until the last page and then the item will be save to mongodb. )     ###  In the scrapy,it's easy to realize by the meta,but in the scrapy_redis i can't know how to do it

Comment: @JKingKong, so are you only using redis to store items temporarily before pushing them to mongo? If so then just disable (comment out) SCHEDULER and DUPEFILTER_CLASS settings which `scrapy-redis` provides.

Comment: I want to use the scrapy_redis to realize a distributed crawler,but i fail in this problems because i don't know how to deal with the item structure

Comment: @JKingKong, if you are filling your item *strictly in succession* then you needn't worry about any of that, however if you are not then the best option you got is to use the actual redis connection. So instead of using python list to hold the image urls you use redis sets/lists (e.g. https://hastebin.com/aqiloyizah.py). That way you allow your mutating structures to be seen by the all running workers.

Comment: Thank you, this is a new method for me,i know how to do it